# How to reuse same Viewcontroller as a Survey in Objective C and change UILabels texts in subsequent views?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I created a custom ViewController which asks questions like a Survey and have tapGesture on the colored (attached image) Views inside the ViewController to record users response... I want to reuse the same ViewController at least 20 times with changing the UILabel (question) and users responses from a JSON file... How can i achieve this ? Should i use Singleton ? I have to capture responses of each questions and save in the Database... Should i end up creating 20+ ViewControllers with tapGestures in it or should i separate this UIViewController from segues and instantiate it 20times in a for loop ? Any help is appreciated.   [image: SampleViewController]

Comment: It sounds as if you only need one instance of the view controller and some logic to change its content.

Comment: Thanks Philip! Should i run different instances in a loop continuously for 20+ times and capture responses in single instance ? Has anyone does something like this before and how do i search for something like this ?